# Pad with 4 pins in allegro cadence (orcad)

Tags: pcb, cadence, allegro

Sorry for silly question, but how to draw pad with four pins? It's not just a custom shape of pad, it has 4 pins.
[image: odd pad]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlap the ground plane pad onto the six pins. I can't recall if Cadence complains about this, but I know I've done it.

The alternate way, without waived errors, is to make the custom shaped pad then have one pin associated with it. There isn't much point in duplicating the information otherwise.

Comment: You mean just make 4 standart pins and in the pcb editor connect them to the ground plane? Sure it possible, but I'm interesting in the possibility to make that in Package designer. And I have no idea how to do it, if I'm trying to connect pins with conductor it gives me DRC error... https://pp.vk.me/c622225/v622225400/2219e/IcL5xfR7ku8.jpg

Comment: You can waive the DRC error, of course, or just make a single pad of that shape and associate it with the (electrically) single pin it connects to.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about just single pad, but on schematics there are four pads.. Ok, thanks for the tips, I'll try to make one pad

Comment: @CybGen It's a MOSFET right? The schematic symbol should only have three pins.

Comment: In the footprint editor: draw 4 separate pads for the drain, overlap them with a copper area or another large pad.